# Using itertools combinations to split data from one cell into two

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column that contains a list of elements. I want to split this column into two columns that are a combination of the original elements.

ex:

```
    data
['x','y','z']
```

This df would become

```
    dataTo    DataFrom
      x          y
      x          z
      y          z
```

I have been trying to use itertools.combinations but don't understand how to leverage that to make two separate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) first, then list comprehension with flattening combinations to list of tuples and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
from  itertools import combinations

print (df)
          dataTo       dataFrom
0  ['x','y','z']  ['a','b','c']

a = [y for x in df[['dataTo','dataFrom']].stack() for y in combinations(x, 2)]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['dataTo','DataFrom'])
print (df)

  dataTo DataFrom
0      x        y
1      x        z
2      y        z
3      a        b
4      a        c
5      b        c
```

Comment: This gives the error: 'data argument can't be an iterator'

Comment: @MaxB - Then need `list` like `pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(a, 2)), columns=['dataTo','DataFrom'])`, because pandas <0.24

Comment: This doesn't seem to behave as expected. It is comparing the entire list to all of the other lists as opposed to breaking down the individual list elements. For instance if there is ['x','y','z'] at index 0 and ['a','b','c'] at index one, the code is comparing ['x',y','z'] to ['a','b','c'] instead of doing it to itself

Comment: @MaxB - hmm, my main problem is not understand, what need. Can you change `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[['x','y','z'],['s','a']]})` to [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add expected output?

Comment: @MaxB - Can you tery before my code `import ast` and `df['data'] = df['data'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` ?

Comment: This gives the error 'malformed node or string'. The elements of the list in my actual dataset contain special characters such as '#, %, &'

Comment: @MaxB - And what about `df['data'] = df['data'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',')` ?

Comment: The following error: 'Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas'

Comment: @MaxB - And `df['data'] = df['data'].astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.split(',')` ?

Comment: This works, and when running the original code after it behaves the same as I updated above in my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193842/discussion-between-jezrael-and-maxb).

Comment: The legend makes it happen yet again folks